# Implementing QuickCheck Arbitrary for algebraic data type with Test.Framework

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am trying to write some quickcheck properties for my ADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2
import Test.Framework.TH
import Test.Framework

-- Stub implementations, not relevant to this problem
encode x = x
decode x = x

data Activity = Run | Walk

instance Arbitrary Activity where
  arbitrary = elements [Run, Walk]

prop_activity_can_be_serialized :: Activity -> Bool
prop_activity_can_be_serialized x = (decode . encode) x == x

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [$testGroupGenerator]
```

This does not compile:

```
Test.hs:23:25:
No instance for (QuickCheck-2.5.1.1:Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary.Arbitrary
                   Activity)
  arising from a use of `testProperty'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (QuickCheck-2.5.1.1:Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary.Arbitrary Activity)
In the expression: testProperty (Test.Framework.TH.fixName n)
In the expression:
  \ n -> testProperty (Test.Framework.TH.fixName n)
In the expression:
  \ n -> testProperty (Test.Framework.TH.fixName n)
    "prop_activity_can_be_serialized" prop_activity_can_be_serialized
```

... but I did add an instance declaration for `Arbitrary Activity`. What am I missing?

Comment: Does `ghc-pkg list QuickCheck` list multiple versions of QuickCheck?

Comment: Aha, it does. Trying to remove them it seems test-framework-quickcheck2 depends on 2.5, but haskell-platform depends on 2.6. From https://github.com/batterseapower/test-framework/pull/50 I think that this is causing instances to be generated for one version to not be recognized by another. Running with `cabal test` works, presumably because it enforces a specific version, but `runhaskell` does not. The latter is much faster though. What is the best way to set my environment up?

Comment: I lied, `cabal test` is *not* working, it's just running an old version that I built.

Comment: I think I almost have this working: https://github.com/yesodweb/cabal-meta/issues/27

Comment: I think tasty (an alternative to test-framework) works with QuickCheck 2.6, maybe you could try that?

Comment: tasty is fantastic, thanks. Switched.